# Почему здесь нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему нет запятой в предложении "хочу стать как мама", а в "ей нравятся такие предметы, как биология, география" есть? И почему в "Необходимо коренным образом изменить отношение к воде как к неограниченному дару природы" тоже нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит думать, что запятая ставится перед союзом КАК в обязательном порядке, постановка запятой зависит **от вида предложения.** Поэтому во всех случаях прежде всего надо определять **грамматику**. Для каждой грамматической конструкции  действуют свои правила.

1. Сравнительный оборот в составе сказуемого не обособляется: *Хочу стать **как мама**.*
2. Сравнительный оборот обособляется  при местоименной связи такой…как:  *Ей нравятся **такие** предметы, **как биология, география**.*
3. Оборот со значением **«в качестве»**  не обособляется (здесь нет сравнения, оборот имеет значение тождества,  приравнивания): *Необходимо коренным образом изменить отношение к воде **как к неограниченному дару природы.***